# Unable to trigger Windows desktop icon install of pwa (progressive web app), using a tested manifest which works on mobile

Tags: progressive-web-apps

PWA works fine on mobile browsers. It does not trigger an icon install on windows desktops. also is there a way to link to the windows store app from the pwa ?

Comment: What browser in windows? Did you try it on a machine that has never visited the site? (to make sure there is nothing in the cache)

Comment: was consistently using Edge to test the site. Then used it on FireFox and Chrome as first use instances on both and again visited the site on these two after about 10 minutes.

Comment: For chrome, add this to the browser address to make sure you have uninstalled any previous tests --> chrome://apps/ <-- and make sure you delete all time cache

Comment: Also: Does your PWA when running with an HTTPS URL pass as a valid PWA with the Chrome Lighthouse tool? If there are issues, it usually gives good hints.

Comment: will check on lighthouse, thnx!